# deduction guide breaks for templated derived class

Tags: c++, inheritance, template-argument-deduction

Here is minimal example:

```
#include <cstddef>
struct base_pod
{
};
template<typename T, std::size_t N>
struct der_pod : public base_pod
{
    T k[N];
};
template<typename T, typename... U>
    der_pod(T, U...)
        ->der_pod<std::enable_if_t<(std::is_same_v<T, U> and ...), T>, 1 + sizeof...(U)>;

int main()
{
    der_pod dp {{}, {3, 3} };
}
```

[live demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/wJGtK1IgQuxnROvw)

```
prog.cc:16:9: error: no viable constructor or deduction guide for deduction of template arguments of 'der_pod'
der_pod dp {{}, {3, 3} };
        ^
prog.cc:11:2: note: candidate template ignored: couldn't infer template argument 'T'
        der_pod(T, U...)
        ^
prog.cc:6:8: note: candidate function template not viable: requires 0 arguments, but 2 were provided
struct der_pod : public base_pod
       ^
prog.cc:6:8: note: candidate function template not viable: requires 1 argument, but 2 were provided
1 error generated.
```

[I have to add explicit template argument`der_pod<int, 2>` to pass compilation.](https://wandbox.org/permlink/lmFPiXYeSiACqEvV)

But deduction guide works fine when it has no base class:

```
template<typename T, std::size_t N>
struct der_pod
{
    T k[N];
};
template<typename T, typename... U>
    der_pod(T, U...)
        ->der_pod<std::enable_if_t<(std::is_same_v<T, U> and ...), T>, 1 + sizeof...(U)>;

int main()
{
    der_pod dp {3, 3};
}
```

[live demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/mvOdZRA9V9ZCMsTV)

#### 1. What's behind?

#### 2. How to fix

Comment: I'm confused. Your second case does not use deduction at all since you specified the arguments yourself. Your first case has no chance to use the deduction guide as `{}` and `{3, 3}` have no type of their own to match `T` and `U`.

Comment: @Quentin Sorry, that's my bad. Updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`{}`, `{3, 3}` have no type and don't allow deduction of `T` and `U`.

Intead, you might use:

```
template <typename T, std::size_t N>
der_pod(base_pod, const T (&)[N]) -> der_pod<T, N>;
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c171903adb4654ae)